# OpenCV fails to read AVI file

Tags: c++, video, opencv, avi

I know there has already been a bunch of questions similar to this, but unfortunately none of them could help. So, here's the problem (I'm quite new to OpenCV).

Trying to simply open and show an AVI file. The file exists and the path to it is correct.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture cap;

    if(!cap.open(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Video output", 1);

    for(;;)
    {
        Mat curFrame;

        cap >> curFrame;

        imshow("Video output\n", curFrame);

        if(waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No errors appear, open() returns false.

I have previously converted the file with mencode. Here is the information about the file:

```
boris@boris-ubuntu:~$ ffmpeg -i out.avi 
ffmpeg version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:37:58 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, avi, from 'out.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : MEncoder svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 265458 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuv420p, 1280x720, PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

As far as I can understand, the video format yuv420p, which is supported by OpenCV.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to open another video?

Comment: Yes, but no effect. Maybe I am missing some libraries needed for opening AVI?

Comment: what is the first argument of your program and where is video file located? It seems to be wrong input file location.

Comment: The file is located in my home directory /home/boris/out.avi. Program is called like ./video_process /home/boris/out.avi.

Comment: Try to put file in the project's directory and call with parameter `out.avi`. Or in your code change `arg[1]` to string `out.avi`.

Comment: I'm not sure if OpenCV supports rawvideo.  Try using a different codec, like MPEG4/H.264 AVC.

Comment: I appreciate your help, many thanks. But the problem was about the ffmpeg in OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was that OpenCV was compiled without ffmpeg (or any other video library) support.

Thanks to [this great post](http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/install-opencv-2-4-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/), I successfully installed ffmpeg and recompiled OpenCV, and then everything was fine.